# Use counting measure to show double series of nonnegative real numbers

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading Papa Rudin, and under theorem 1.27, it says: If we let $\mu$ be the counting measure on a countable set, Theorem 1.27 is a statement about double series of nonnegative real numbers:

If $a_{ij} \geq 0$ for i and j = 1,2,3,..., then

$$\Sigma_{i=1}^\infty \Sigma_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij} = \Sigma_{j=1} \Sigma_{i=1} a_{ij}$$ I don't understand here. How theorem 1.27 can be applied here?

Theorem 1.27 is that we can switch limit and sum.

Comment: Tonelli's theorem. Convert the summations into integrals via Counting measure and apply the theorem.

Comment: I doubt that. The book doesn't mention Tonelli's theorem here.

Comment: Let $X=\Bbb{N}$, with the $\sigma$-algebra being the power set, and $\mu$ the counting measure. Let $f_n:X\to [0,\infty]$ be given as $f_n(m)=a_{nm}$. Now, unwind the definitions in the equality $\int_{\Bbb{N}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n\,d\mu=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{\Bbb{N}}f_n\,d\mu$ (which holds by theorem 1.27).

Comment: @Mariana Theorem 1.27 is literally just a corollary of Tonelli's theorem. But I wouldn't know that since you didn't write up Theorem 1.27